# asp.net mvc error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i'm a newbie .net mvc developer and i want to know, is there anyway to develop my own error handler without using the famous try/catch statement. i'm using an XML file to render components in a view, and i want for example to get an error message useful for me to know that i violated a constraint based on the xml file

> (example  if i add another tag without >'type' attribute, this can generate a message for me at runtime). i hope i make myself clear
>   thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i prefer using the ActionFilter class to override the OnActionExecuting, OnActionExecuted,OnResultExecuting and OnResultExecuted method. 
And i think that the control of xml properties cannot be done from c sharp, well i will use the if condition for that.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

In the Global.asax can catch the exceptions, global.asax has many handlers of events on your aplication like Application_start or that you need Application_Error

```
void Application_Error(){

     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
     //do what you need with the exception...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best place for handling exceptions is in global.asax.cs.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // custom logger
    IErrorLogger errorLogger = new CustomLogger();

    // config of error handler
    MvcExceptionHandlerConfig config = new MvcExceptionHandlerConfig("Error", "Error", 404, 500);

    // init and handle
    new MvcExceptionHandler.MvcExceptionHandler(this, errorLogger, config).Handle();
}
```

Demo is available here: https://github.com/mholec/mvcexceptionhandler

Of course, it depends, what kind of exceptions you want to handle. Application_Error is great place for handling errors 400, 404, 5xx etc., on the other hand it is not usable for authentication errors (you need to create special filter).